# Gpresult provides wrong output on vista machine regarding UAC settings

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, group-policy, windows-vista

I have two workstations running Windows 7 Professional 64bit with SP1 and Windows Vista Business 32bit with SP2. Both are in the same OU and have a GPO linked named `Hardening_Computers_Clients`.

This are the defined settings within the GPO:

[image]

This is what `gpresult`tells me on the Windows 7 machine:

[image]

And here the `gpresult`output on the Windows Vista machine:

[image]

I ran `gpupdate /force` several times, rebooted more then twice but the gpresult output remains the same on the vista machine (notice the difference in the `Behavior of the elevation prompt for ...` setting).

However UAC works as expected on the Vista machine (switches to the secure desktop and asks for username and password), but why does it keep telling me wrong settings? Also some of the configured settings are missing...

**P.S:** I am 100% positive that `Hardening_Computers_Clients` is the winning GPO on both machines, I had to cut it off from the screenshot for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually in relation to AGPM - do you have it installed anywhere?  I typically run it on my local machine (I am running Windows 8.1) and then I pull the PC in question.

AGPM = Advanced Group policy management

It comes with MDOP if you have MSDN/TechNet.  If not, you need to run Group Policy management from a machine with windows 8 kernel (2012 R2, 8, 8.1, 10, etc) to access more settings.

Microsoft introduced many changes to all three with each iteration which is why it can look different.

Comment: I do not run AGPM. Everything got configured on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine.

Comment: There's your answer!  is the 2012R2 machine you're GPO Admin/DC?

Comment: It's not a DC, but I did configure all my GPOs on that machine, yes.